# cut elimination for infinitary logic

Tags: logic

Takeuti (1987, 223) derives a cut-elimination theorem for infinitary logic from the soundness-and-completeness theorems.  However, is there a way to adapt the original Gentzen-style proof?

The relevant version of the cut rule is (roughly)

From proofs of $\Gamma\to \Delta,A_\alpha$ for all $\alpha<\lambda$ and a proof of $\{A_\alpha\}_{\alpha<\lambda}, \Pi\to \Lambda$,

obtain a proof of $\Gamma,\Pi\to \Delta,\Lambda$.

The obstacles I can see are these... The notion of rank used in the original Gentzen argument (as in Takeuti, 23) assumes that a mix has only two upper sequents, which is not so in the infinite case.

Also, in the original argument, the transformations involved in reducing the left-rank of a proof ending in a mix depend on which rule was used to obtain the upper sequent $\Gamma\to\Delta,A$; but with the infinitary cut rule there will in general be many upper-left sequents, these obtained by many different rules.

So, to clarify the question a little: are the adaptations required 
(i) routine? ...(hint?)
(ii) hairy but done someplace? ...(reference?)
(iii) impossible? ...(explanation?)?

Sorry for the slightly lazy question, but I am both old and a novice...

Thanks-in-advance,

Max

PS: by 'infinitary logic' I mean what Takeuti calls 'a system of infinitary logic with homogeneous quantifiers' (1987, 211ff).  Roughly speaking, this system generalizes sequent calculus for first-order logic by allowing up-to-card(L)-many simultaneous applications of any given 'finitary' rule, where card(L) is the cardinality of the set of formulas of L.